# set secure cookie in sails.js app

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies, redis, sails.js

What is the way to configure sails.js to set secure cookies? We are using redis to persist session state. The sails.js prescribed way (rather than some Express middleware option) is desired. Ultimately, I want the "secure" column in the Chrome cookies view to be checked for the app's cookie:

[image]

In the docs, there is no explicit mention of how to do this:

http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/reference/sails.config/sails.config.session.html

There is an `ssl` config option, but deploying the app with `ssl: true` did not produce the desired result:

```
module.exports.session = {
  ...
  ssl: true
  ...
}
```

The `ssl` option isn't documented either, but I assume it has something to do with signing cookies instead.

**edit**: in the screen shot, I'm serving from localhost without HTTPS, but this app is being served from a production server using HTTPS and the same behavior is observed

Comment: `secure` in Chrome means the cookies are limited to a "secure" scope (which usually means HTTPS). If you're serving your website through HTTPS, I think that you can use `secure : true` in your session configuration; that's how [Express's session middleware](https://github.com/expressjs/session#cookie-options) works, though, not sure about Sails.js.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sails uses express.session to handle session cookies, therefore you can enable secure cookies by setting `cookie: { secure: true }` in config/session.js

You need to use HTTPS for express to [set the cookie](https://github.com/expressjs/session#cookie-options)

> it requires an https-enabled website, i.e., HTTPS is necessary for secure
>   cookies. If secure is set, and you access your site over HTTP, 
>   the cookie will not be set.

If you are behind a proxy that does SSL termination on behalf of your web server enable express `trust proxy` option by adding the following middleware in config/http.js

```
    module.exports.http = {
      customMiddleware: function(app) {
        app.enable('trust proxy');
      }
    };
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Works perfectly.

Comment: I believe that this was introduced for 1.0, not present in 0.12.

Comment: @Ofer - I tried enabling secure cookie + the trust proxy config in v0.12 and the sails.sid/cookie did not appear in the browser, is there something else required? Or does this only work in v1.0?

Comment: @Aaron since the answer is 4 years old I think it was sails v0.12 or even an earlier version

Comment: @Aaron - have you found how to do this?

Comment: @Vikranth - Unfortunately, I tried Ofer's suggestion but did not work. Still haven't figured out why it won't show the secure cookie.

Comment: @Aaron - any solution then to view the user's session. I was planning to use the Sails.sid for getting the user's id. If this does not work, do you have any solutions for this?

Comment: @Vikranth - unfortunately I wasn't able to get it working... I'm using PaaS and believe the proxy needs to be trusted too. With sails, they're bundling the Heroku deployment script...

Answer (score 0):

It appears that there is not a way to do this currently. If you look at the sails.js session implementation here (https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/blob/98522d0bc5df5e6bc30b4dc35708ae71cf4625e2/lib/hooks/session/index.js) you'll see that there is, in fact, no secure-mode stuff whatsoever :(

Since sails is using their own session store implementation, and not piggybacking off of [node-client-sessions](https://github.com/mozilla/node-client-sessions) or [express-sessions](https://github.com/expressjs/session), the only way to solve this (I think) would be to submit a PR to the sails people.

Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

You can set signed cookies like so

Adding a signed cookie named "chocolatechip" with value "Yummy:

```
res.cookie('chocolatechip', 'Yummy', {signed:true});
```

Retrieving the cookie:

```
req.signedCookies.chocolatechip; //"Yummy"
```

check out the sails [Documentation](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/request-req/req-signed-cookies)